# Pycharm typehint for Numpy array of objects

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, pycharm

I have multiple `numpy` arrays with different objects. How can I give 'type-hint' to the Pycharm so that I can get methods of that class while coding? For example,

```py
import numpy as np

class Test:
    def do_task():
       pass

data = [Test(), Test(), Test()]
my_array = np.array(data, dtype=Test)

def test_hint(array:np.ndarray):  # <-- I can give typehint as array but I also want to give hint about what kind of array it is.
    for a in array:
         a.... # Here I want Pycharm to give me list of methods from 'Test' class
```

I can always explicitly mention what kind of object it is like following,

```py
for a in array:
   temp = a # type: Test
   temp... # Here Pycharm will give me all the suggestions.
```

Is there any way I can provide type-hint in the constructor so that I do not need to write additional line of code to declare type of data? I tried looking at python's `type` module for some clue, but couldn't find any.

Comment: Why are you using array here?  Iterating on `data` would be faster.  It might not help with your hint problem, but I expect there's more discussion about doing this with lists than with arrays.

Comment: @hpaulj I have to use array because my program requires lot of reshaping of the data which is much easier with `numpy` array or  `matrix` than regular iterators.

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59179493/numpy-typehint-with-nptyping-and-array-in-pycharm