# Numpy Typehint with nptyping and Array in PyCharm

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm, numpy-ndarray, type-hinting

I try to use numpy with `nptyping`'s `Array` to do my typehinting.

I tried the following:

```py
enemy_hand: Array[float, 48] = np.zeros(48)
```

I get an typerror:

> Expected Type 'Array[float, Any]', got 'ndarray' instead

as far as I understand from this: https://pypi.org/project/nptyping/ thats how it should look.

Comment: What line gives you that error? type hinting is only for the user. Also I tried to replicate your problem but `isinstance` gives the expected outputs. Please update your question to include some more information about the error and how you're encountering it

Comment: @sshashank124 as pointed out in a comment on my deleted answer, asker is trying to do [Variable Annotation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`nptyping` is currently useless for static analysis. Quoting a [post](https://github.com/ramonhagenaars/nptyping/issues/8#issuecomment-572438916) by the library's developer on its issue tracker,

> `mypy` is just not supported by `nptyping` (yet)

I wouldn't put much hope in that "yet". NumPy's dtype and shape handling is very hard to fit into the `typing`/`mypy` static type model, and `nptyping`'s own design decisions are a poor fit for NumPy itself. For example, it doesn't look like the dev ever considered arrays that aren't 2D, so `Array[str, 3]` represents a 2D array with 3 rows and unspecified columns instead of a 3-element 1D array. All the implementation is in terms of rows and columns, too.

As far as I can tell, the only real functionality `nptyping` has is `isinstance` checks, and even that's buggy.

Comment: @NameVergessen: No. Like I said, NumPy's dtype and shape handling is a very poor match for the `typing`/`mypy` type system.

Comment: as far as i can tell the yet isn't here (yet).

Comment: FYI, Still not yet

Comment: For `nptyping` 2.x, `mypy` can detect array vs non-array but cannot detect shape/dimension label mismatch.